# How to retrieve data according to another cell?

Tags: excel-formula

I have a table on the first column its mentioned about the endorsement type, 2nd column name and on 3rd column, according to the endorsement type it generates `active or deleted`

Below is the table and against `LANA EL EIT` each time his name displayed the status should be `deleted` as on endo type this member is deleted in the last endorsement rest all will display `Active`

```
Endo type            Beneficiary First Name   Status
----------           ----------------------   -------
Initial New          ELISSAR IDRISS

Initial New          LANA EL EIT

Initial New          MOHAMMAD EL EIT

Initial New          ABDO IBRAHIM ABDO

Voluntary Deletion   LANA EL EIT
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
=IF(A2="Voluntary Deletion","Deleted","Active")
```

Drag this down your 3rd column